# Animator.Play not working Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to play an animation on other gameobject from a different script.

```
public GameObject batsman;
private Animator batsmanAnimation;
```

First i initialized the game object then dragged and dropped the object to its place in inspector.

In Start function,

```
batsmanAnimation = batsman.GetComponent<Animator> ();
```

Then I want to play an animation when someone press the left shift button,

```
  if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift)) {
                batsmanAnimation.Play ("batting");
                Debug.Log ("Is Batting");
        }
```

> Console prints "Is Batting"

Batting Animation Properties,

[image: batting]

Player Properties,

[image: player properties]

Comment: Its the Animator component, it manages the animation states and etc. It doesnt play anything because most likely you dont have an animation with a name "batting". https://koenig-media.raywenderlich.com/uploads/2015/10/Created-Animation-and-Animator.png. This is a good example of how it should look like in the inspector. With the script you have to arrange everything to be in the same way.

Comment: do you mean the Start function? there's no such this as onStart fucntion in unity's API, do you get an error when you try to play the animation?

Comment: @ArmanPapikyan I added the player property inspector ss. ANd there is an animation with the name of batting.

Comment: @IdoBenShalom Sorry! used onStart so many times while doing android programming. So accidentally wrote it. And yeah I have edited the post with animator and player window. Please check it out.

Comment: you should create an idle state with no animation and go from entry to idle animation and from that to the other animations that you've created, also you should call batsmanAnimation.SetBool("isBatting", true); from the looks of it

Comment: It worked after enabling loop on that animation. @IdoBenShalom. But I don't want loop. Are there anything I'm missing?

Comment: did you try to do what i worte in the last comment?\

Comment: Yeah I added idle then using .play() function works. But still setBool condition is not working. Anyways thank you so much for helping...